# How to remove rows of a data frame using a separate vector

Tags: filtering, satellite, telemetry

I am trying to filter a data frame that contains Argos locations of any implausible locations using sdafilter function that is part of the argosfilter package.

This is a section of the vector output when the sdafilter is run, it has 3 elements:

1. "removed" (location removed by the filter)
2. "end_location" (location at the end of the track where the algorithm could not be applied)
3. "not" (location not removed):

`[1] "end_location" "end_location" "removed"      "removed"      "removed"`
 `[6] "removed"      "removed"      "not"          "not"          "not"`
 `[11] "not"          "removed"      "not"          "not"          "removed"`
 `[16] "not"          "not"          "not"          "not"          "removed"`
 `[21] "not"          "not"          "not"          "not"          "not"`
 `[26] "not"          "not"          "not"          "not"          "not"`

The data points that are returned in the vector as "removed" are points which are implausible given the set criteria specified in the sdafilter function. I want to apply this vector to my data frame to remove all rows that correspond with where "removed" is displayed in the vector.

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the following [example](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/argosfilter/versions/0.63/topics/sdafilter/#l_examples).

If you want to specifically store the not filtered values into a new data frame, you could use `cbind` like in the example below:

```r
library(argosfilter)

data(seal)
lat<-seal$lat
lon<-seal$lon
dtime<-seal$dtime

mfilter<-vmask(lat,lon,dtime,2)

lon[4:8]
lat[4:8]
mfilter[4:8]
not_Removed <- cbind(lon[which(mfilter=="not")],lat[which(mfilter=="not")])
not_Removed[1:5,1:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your lat, lon, dtime and lc set, as per instructions detailed on the package documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argosfilter/argosfilter.pdf), you can get the vector captured in 'filtered', which you then attach to your original data frame.

You can then create a second data frame, which only keeps rows based on the condition you set (in this case, removing coordinates and their respective rows if the filter deemed them implausible).

```
filtered <- sdafilter(lat, lon, dtime, lc, vmax = 5, ang =  c(15,25))
df$filter <- filtered
df_cleaned <- df[df$df != "removed", ] 

nrow(df)
nrow(df_cleaned)
```

You can check that rows were removed by counting the rows between the data frames.